# Configure .htaccess to block bot indexing but allow browser directory listing/viewing

Tags: .htaccess, indexing, directoryindex

I know in order to show a directory listing of my files in a browser through `.htaccess` I can use

```
Options +Indexes
```

and to prevent Google and most bots from crawling my directory I can use

```
Options -Indexes
```

Is it possible to still allow a visible directory listing through a browser but prevent bot crawling/indexing solely with `.htaccess`?

Comment: Why are you not using robots.txt?

Comment: It's just a question of curiosity regarding .htaccess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` file cannot magically distinguish "real" users from "bot" users. Since from the webserver's perspective, there is no distinction.

However, as a general rule, bots will respect the contents of `robots.txt`, while web browsers do not.

Alternately, if you had some way of determining what was a bot and what was not, you could work that rule into your `.htaccess` configuration. A common tactic is to apply a set of  RewriteRules that filter based on the reported `User-Agent` header. For example, a user-agent that contains the word "googlebot" is *probably* run by Google.

[User-Agents.org](http://www.user-agents.org/) has a list of popular user-agent identifiers. But remember that the contents of this header are set by the person running the bot/browser, and can contain anything she wants it to. So, for example, malicious users will typically copy the User-Agent string from a popular browser or perhaps a popular search engine. So you can't depend on this.